# C# record - Assign Multiple Properties using Reflection On Same Instance

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, record

Since `record` type is immutable, a new instance is created whenever a property is set

My question is: using **reflection**, is it possible to set values to multiple properties without creating new instance on every assignment (same as `with` reserved word)?

Thank you!

```
public class Program
{
    public record Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine("Hashcode BEFORE property assignment: " + p.GetHashCode());
        var pis = p.GetType().GetProperties( BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        
        foreach (var pi in pis)
        {
            pi.SetValue(p, "f"); //this line creates and assign a new instance (record is immutable)
            Console.WriteLine($"Hashcode AFTER \'{pi.Name}\' property assignment: " + p.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `record` types are not immutable by default

Answer (score 2):

> //this line creates and assign a new instance (record is immutable)

I would argue that this statement is not true.

```cs
var p = new Person();
var p1 = p;

// ... your code

Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(p, p1)); // prints True
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mq8Wmo).

The hash code change does not prove that a new instance is created - records [have `GetHashCode` generated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#equality-members) which will include the declared fields (check at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQzABATgpgxgeygEwgBRlAzggdgWACgBvIgSHAhAEYAGCAMQEtsAXAOQEMBbGCYiAHMYrANwQsI8QF8i5SjXoAZTlg48+A4WIlSIswtKA=)) so changing a field will lead to the hash code change.

So answering your question:

> using reflection, is it possible to set values to multiple properties without creating new instance on every assignment

Yes, it is because no new instance created when you manipulate properties with reflection.

Comment: @RoiShabtai I'm not following you. Your question especially says _"using reflection, is it possible..."_.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?
If you look at the [C# reference for records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record):

> You can also create records with mutable properties and fields:

```
public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = default!;
};
```

Ideally there is no reason to use reflection to set those property

but if you want to create an immutable record you should be doing so using one of the following examples.

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);

public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; init; } = default!;
};
```

However this doesn't prevent using reflection.

Comment: The question rose while creating generic method for updating databse records. In the implementation we iterate all properties. the problem - every assignment creates new instance. So I was wander if there is equal command to with using reflection

Comment: Hmm, reflection should still work.  Why are you using reflection manually for the generic method, you can use something like AutoMapper which will create castle proxies, and handle updates way more efficiently

Comment: @Ritzt Dev - there are many options for workaround, still the question is focusing on achiving the with functionality using reflection

Comment: @RoiShabtai yeah I was just making sure you knew about the other options